# what can't my google map work after parsing lat and lng

Tags: android

I would like to know what is wrong with my google map.
When I try to parse the value of one class latitude and longitude to another class to use the google map, it wouldn't work.

I'm getting the the URL from " ",
which I need the value for "latitude" and "longitude" to parse to my Google Map.
I'm able to retrieve the data for latitude and longitude.

However, when I try to parse value into google map,
it doesn't work,giving my force close error.
May i know what is wrong with my code?

my code of onclick part:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("coords", "lat: " + KEY_LATITUDE + " long: " + KEY_LONGITUDE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, map.class);
        intent.putExtra("LAT", KEY_LATITUDE.toString());
        intent.putExtra("LON", KEY_LONGITUDE.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
```

map.java

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity {
    // double lat;
    // double lng;

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_shown);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fm.getMap();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        String lat = null;
        String lon = null;
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat, lon),
                14.0f));

    }

    private LatLng LatLng(String lat, String lon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        lat = extras.getString("LAT");
        lon = extras.getString("LON");
        return null;
    }

}
```

logcat error:

```
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fambond/com.example.fambond.map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at maps.al.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at maps.ag.af.a(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at maps.ag.s.a(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at maps.ag.an.a(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at bkw.onTransact(SourceFile:83)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at com.example.fambond.map.onCreate(map.java:28)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-14 15:21:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(24718):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all LatLng method has 2 doubles as parameters!

Second your LatLng method is returning null so its obviously that you will get an NPE and your app will shutdown.

Try to change your code accordingly:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("coords", "lat: " + KEY_LATITUDE + " long: " + KEY_LONGITUDE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, map.class);
    intent.putExtra("LAT", KEY_LATITUDE);
    intent.putExtra("LON", KEY_LONGITUDE);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then.

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity {
 double lat;
 double lng;

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_shown);

    lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LAT");
    lon = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("LON");

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = fm.getMap();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(getLatLng()),
            14.0f));

}

private LatLng getLatLng() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new LatLng(lat,lon);
}
```

}

Also from your code i am assuming that you still need work to do with Java! Try to practice it more or else you wont be able to afford App Development at Android.

Comment: hi, the putdouble is being highlighted.

previously, I declared the lat and lng as string in the above

Comment: hello(:
it can open the map without error, but why the code that I wanted to parse, don't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to your lines of code. In your private LatLng LatLng(String lat, String lon) method :

```
private LatLng LatLng(String lat, String lon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    lat = extras.getString("LAT");
    lon = extras.getString("LON");

    // Add these lines of changed code
    Double slatObject = Double.parseDouble(lat) / 1E6;
    Double slngObject = Double.parseDouble(lon) / 1E6;
    LatLng latlng_points = new LatLng(slatObject,slngObject);
    return latlng_points;
}
```